# C++ If Loop Error

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program that will guess a number you input. I'm kind of confused on what I'm doing wrong. The program compiles, and everything works, but to a point. The program works until it asks you for an input after it guesses 2 times. On the 3rd time the program exits. For example say my number is 700. The program will always guess 500 the first time. Since 700 is more than 500 you would select the option for "Higher" (Code below). The program would change the variable "Low" From 0 to 500, the current guess. Then it would add the "Low" to the "High" (1000 at the first guess) and change the answer to the "Guess" variable. Then it would take the "Guess" variable and divide it by 2, making this the new guess, then printing it out as a guess in the program. So if the number was more than 500, the second guess would be 750. Now this time the equation will change. It will change the "High" variable to the current guess, and add the "Low" to the "High" once again. The answer will be changed to the guess and then divided by 2 once more, giving 625. Since 700 is still higher than 625, it will again use the equation from the first input. But instead of doing this, the program just exits. Any help? If I need to further elaborate (again) please say so.
I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in the if loop where I have

```
if (status == ...)
```

and so on.

Code:

```
#include #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int number,low,high,guess,guesses,status;
low = 0;
high = 1000;
guesses = 0;
cout<<"Please pick a number between 1 and 1000 \n";
do
    {
        cin>>number;
        if (number > 1000) cout<<"Please pick a number less than 1000 \n";
    } while (number > 1000);
cout<<"Thank you. Now I will guess your number! \n";
guess=500;
cout<<"Is your number "<<guess<<"? \n";
cout<<"[1] Yes \n"<<"[2] Higher \n"<<"[3] Lower \n";
do
    {
        cin>>status;
        if ( (status != 1) && (status != 2) && (status != 3) ) cout<<"Please select option 1, 2, or 3 \n";
    } while ( (status != 1) && (status != 2) && (status != 3) );
do
    {   
        if (status == 2)
        low=guess;
        guess=low+high;
        guess=guess/2;
        guesses=guesses+1;
        cout<<"Is your number "<<guess<<"? \n";
        cout<<"[1] Yes \n"<<"[2] Higher \n"<<"[3] Lower \n";
        cin>>status;
        if (status == 3)
        high=guess;
        guess=low+high;
        guess=guess/2;
        guesses=guesses+1;
        cout<<"Is your number "<<guess<<"? \n";
        cout<<"[1] Yes \n"<<"[2] Higher \n"<<"[3] Lower \n";
        cin>>status;
        if (status == 1)
        cout<<"I guessed your number! It only took me "<<guesses<<" tries to guess it!";
    } while ( (status = 3) && (status = 2) && (status = 1) );
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The first line in your last loop `if (status = 2);` does probably not what you intended. It always changes `status` to 2 and nothing else. You want something like `if (status == 2) { ... }`.
Edit: My advice is to always use `{}` after an `if` to make you code less error-prone - especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: If you "get errors at lines 28, 36, and 44" then your program does ***not*** compile.  When dealing with computers in general, "I get errors" is not considered an acceptable description of a problem.  When programming, doubly so.

Comment: ^^^ error/warning messages please.  Also, note that SO code sections do not have line numbers.

Comment: Added my Error Logs, going to try adding == instead of just =. Also would it work if I used || instead of &&? I get confused on which one is "or" and which one is "and"

Comment: Have you heard of paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have some questionable code here. For example,

```
if (status = 2);
```

What is the purpose of this? First of all, if you wanted to compare if `status` is equal to 2, the correct syntax is:

```
if (status == 2)
```

Second, even with the correct syntax, the lines ends with a semicolon (;). That means that you have an empty statement that is executed if the `if` condition is true.

Finally, when posting questions like this, please indicate which lines are causing the errors. Stackoverflow code listings do not show line numbers, and it's a little unreasonable to expect someone to count all your lines just so they can help you.

Comment: I apologize for assuming that Stackoverflow listed line numbers, but I added the logs that gave the errors that showed the line that gave the errors. Also changed to if (status == ....), Taking off the semicolon just ends the program after the 3rd input.

Comment: @JarrodA. update your code in the question

Comment: Updated code, sorry for sloppy work, trying to do 5 things at once :/

Comment: @JarrodA. the same advice goes for the `while` loop. `status=3` is an assignment, which by the way returns the value that was assigned to staus (3), which in turn will be interpreted as `true`. So the last loop should actually run forever.

Comment: if block missing `{..}`..terminates when finds first semicolon in your case `if (status == 2)
        low=guess;` and it terminates